# Gráfico de perfis de média (incluindo as barras de erro)

Tags: r, gráfico

Tenho um dataset que intitulei malaria, que pode ser baixado neste [link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~mbranco/dadosmalariaCEA15P14.csv). Preciso construir um gráficos de perfis de média (incluindo as barras de erro) da variável peso do recém nascido (coluna 'peso'), segundo grupo de tipo de parasita (coluna 'grupo' onde 0 = controle, 1 = vivax, 2 = falciparum, 3 = mista). Código que usei para separ o peso dos bebês por cada grupo:

`controle = malaria$peso[malaria['grupo']==0]
vivax = malaria$peso[malaria['grupo']==1]
falciparum = malaria$peso[malaria['grupo']==2]
mista = malaria$peso[malaria['grupo']==3]`

Preciso plotar a média destes quatro grupos, interligadas por uma linha e com barras, em torno desse ponto de média, que informam o desvio padrão de cada grupo. Seria um gráfico como da figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente o pacote sciplot, disponível no Cran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu recomendo usar os pacotes `ggplot2` e `Rmisc` para fazer este gráfico. O primeiro pacote faz o gráfico em si, enquanto o segundo prepara os dados para a análise. Abaixo vou explicar o passo a passo de como construí o gráfico desejado.

Em primeiro lugar, utilizo a função `summarySE` para obter as médias e erros padrão do conjunto de dados desejado. Veja que bastou informar o nome da data frame, a variável resposta e a variável de agrupamento para obter o que desejamos.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)

malaria.plot <- summarySE(malaria, measurevar="peso", groupvars="grupo", na.rm=TRUE)
```

Em seguida, para o gráfico ficar com os labels do eixo x com os nomes corretos, sem o uso de números, converti a coluna `grupo` em fator. Abaixo mostro o resultado final desta preparação dos dados.

```
malaria.plot$grupo <- factor(c("Controle", "Vivax", "Falciparum", "Mista"), 
  levels=c("Controle", "Vivax", "Falciparum", "Mista"))
malaria.plot
       grupo   N     peso       sd       se        ci
1   Controle 206 3225.830 510.6585 35.57927  70.14821
2      Vivax 173 3134.098 508.4377 38.65580  76.30084
3 Falciparum 100 3122.550 512.6327 51.26327 101.71744
4      Mista  56 3144.696 489.7987 65.45211 131.16896
```

Com os dados prontos, basta fazer o gráfico. Utilizei a função `ggplot` juntamente com `geom_errorbar`, considerando os cálculos presentes em `malaria.plot`. Perceba que não estou plotando o conjunto de dados original, mas sim a transformação que fiz nos dados. Utilizo também `geom_line` e `geom_point` para fazer os pontos e as linhas unindo-os. Por fim, `labs` acrescenta os nomes aos eixos.

```
ggplot(malaria.plot, aes(x=grupo, y=peso, group=1)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=peso-se, ymax=peso+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Grupo", y="Peso (kg)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não queira o fundo cinza na imagem, adicione `+ theme_bw()` ao comando acima. Outros detalhes do gráfico podem ser ajustados procurando o help do `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 3):

É possível usar a função **stat_summary()**, do ggplot2, para sumarizar as observações. Usando o ggplot2, não é preciso separar os grupos em vetores diversos, bastando indicar o parâmetro estático group=, em cada uma das instruções.

Primeiramente, converti previamente os grupos para um dado tipo factor, atribuindo os níveis adequados conforme você indica na separação dos grupos:

```
malaria$grupo = as.factor(malaria$grupo)
levels(malaria$grupo) = c("controle","vivax","falciparum","mista")
```

Em seguida, plotei o gráfico a partir das médias como pontos, usei a função mean_cl_normal() para gerar os intervalos de confiança e plotá-los como barras de erro, e liguei as médias usando uma linha tracejada - cada uma destas operações usando apenas stat_summary():

```
ggplot(malaria,aes(group=grupo,y=peso,x=grupo)) + 
 stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point") + 
 stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, geom="errorbar") + 
 stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",aes(group=""),linetype="dashed")
```

[image: Gráfico gerado para comparar peso ao nascer e grupos de Malária.]

Maiores informações sobre [stat_summary() podem ser encontradas na documentação do ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html).

Answer (score -2):

Quando eu tento colocar essa linha ligando os pontos, isso não acontece e elas ficam paralelas as barras de erro. Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Muito obrigada

Comment: Isto não responde realmente à pergunta. Se você tiver uma pergunta diferente, pode fazê-la clicando em [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Você também pode [adicionar uma gratificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para chamar mais atenção a esta pergunta quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/357529)